# Oracle undo analyze table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing an assignment on indexing and optimizing queries and rushed a little too far with analyzing my table.
I'd like to get some data of the state and costs of before performing this command:

```
analyze table TAB1 compute statistics;
```

Is there a way to "unanalyze" a table?

In case it helps: I'm using oracle 11.2G and SQL*Developer 4.1

Comment: No, you cannot undo it, but you can delete it (statistic).

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov , yes, that worked perfectly! thank you!

Comment: You say you are on Oracle11gR2. So you should be using DBMS_STATS rather than `analyze`

Comment: APC is correct. `analyze` has been deprecated for gather statistics. You should **really** use `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats()`

Comment: yes, and dbms_stats.delete_table_stats to remove stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DBMS_STATS` package allows you to save and re-apply old statistics.

### Create the initial table and data

Create a simple table with 100K rows.

```
--drop table tab1;
create table tab1(a number);
insert into tab1 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TAB1');
end;
/
```

### View original stats

Note that the estimated number of rows is set to 100K in the `Rows` column.

```
explain plan for select * from tab1;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 2211052296

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   100K|   488K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB1 |   100K|   488K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Save the original statistics

```
begin
    dbms_stats.create_stat_table(user, 'TAB1_OLD_STATS');
    dbms_stats.export_table_stats(user, 'TAB1', stattab => 'TAB1_OLD_STATS');
end;
/
```

### Change the statistics

After changing the statistics `Rows` is set to 99M.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.set_table_stats(user, 'TAB1', numrows => 99999999);
end;
/

explain plan for select * from tab1;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 2211052296

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    99M|   476M|   793  (92)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB1 |    99M|   476M|   793  (92)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Revert to the old statistics

Using `DBMS_STATS.IMPORT_TABLE_STATS` the statistics are reverted to the old values and `Rows` is back to 100K.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.import_table_stats(user, 'TAB1', stattab => 'TAB1_OLD_STATS');
end;
/


explain plan for select * from tab1;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 2211052296

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   100K|   488K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB1 |   100K|   488K|    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```